# Customize MOSS People Picker (PeopleEditor) Control

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, peoplepicker

I have modified my MOSS 2007 configuration to query a given target AD successfully.  I would like to show some custom LDAP fields (such as country) in the PeopleEditor control and allow users to search against these fields.  Can someone point me towards useful resources/tutorials showing how to do this?

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inherit from the EntityEditor control (just as PeopleEditor does) and write your own queries and validation.

Some background (read community content):

- [EntityEditorWithPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.entityeditorwithpicker.aspx)
- [PickerDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.pickerdialog.aspx)
- [SimpleQueryControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.simplequerycontrol.aspx)

Along with these links and carefully studying the PeopleEditor control with Reflector, another good resource is [this blog post from Igor Kozlov](http://igorinnet.blogspot.com/2007/10/customizing-entityeditorwithpicker.html). There's a less detailed but still useful [example on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc889345.aspx).

I'm working on [a CodePlex project](http://sppeopleactive.codeplex.com/) that queries any given Active Directory from a people picker. It's well documented and combines techniques from the various references out on the web (giving credit of course). Hope it helps someone as well!

Comment: Alex, Thanks for answering.  I had already came across Igor's post and had started work using the EntityEditor, based on Igor's post. +1

Answer (score 0):

A first step should be to map the fields form the AD to a attribute in the SharePoint user profile. You can do this in the configuration of the Share Service Provider (Central Administration > Shared Services > User Profiles and Properties).

There you add a new attribute and define which AD field should be mapped to it. You can also define which fields the users are allowed to override (but only in SharePoint, it's only a one ways synchronization) and which one are read only.

This [blog post](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2006/07/found-it-how-to-add-properties-to.html) shows how to configure the SharePoint search to be able to search users by a custom attribute in the user profile.

I hope this will point you into the right direction.

Comment: @Flo:You are right at what you said, but his question is to exposing those fields in the People picker control. Not in the People search as you mentioned

Comment: Kusek, beat me to it.  Flo, thanks for answering, but I am specifically looking at modifying the PeopleEditor control.