# Extend sharepoint peopleeditor control

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I would like to customize wss peopleeditor control so it searches user profiles by job title or some other property than login name. Can anybody provide me with some hint or maybe tutorial for something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Below link might be useful to you.

[Customize MOSS People Picker (PeopleEditor) Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378661/customize-moss-people-picker-peopleeditor-control)

Answer (score 1):

Also if you would like to replace all current (those built into SharePoint pages) PeopleEditor controls with your custom ones, you may want to see [Guest blog by NaT - SharePoint People Picker: Override Validation Logic](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2009/06/20/sharepoint-people-picker-override-validation-logic.aspx)